# PHP mail() function is not sending

Tags: php, email, server

I am trying to send an email using PHP 
I'm using this form:

```
<form class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" action="contact.php">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="Text" placeholder="Nome" name="Name">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
         </fieldset>
         <fieldset>
        <button type="Reset" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Limpar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Enviar</button>
        </fieldset>

</form>
```

and this php code

```
<?php
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];

$mail_to = 'nelson.maia@geralucros.com';
$subject = 'GeraRelax: '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'De: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";

$headers = 'De: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Responder para: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = @mail($mail_to, $subject, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Obrigado pela contacto.');
        window.location = 'index.php';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Envio falhado');
        window.location = 'index.php';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

I have used it before but now it doesn't work. I'm guessing this have to do with server configurations?
Can someone enlighten me on this?

Comment: By the way the @before the mail didn't exist till 30 sec, saw a similar question here and that was the answer, didn't work for me tho

Comment: are you doing this from local machine or a hosted server ?

Comment: who is it done via ? maybe if it's not a code issue it could be worth looking at there FAQ or docs a lot of providers don't allow you to send emails without extra config.

Comment: websitex5 at this moment. my boss should by the godaddy host today

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the form METHOD!

```
<form class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" action="contact.php" METHOD="POST">
```

Also missing . to add to headers.

```
$headers .= 'De: '.$field_email."\r\n";
```

Also type in NOME should be NAME

```
<input type="Text" placeholder="Nome" name="Name">
```

TYPO IN VARIABLE NAMES

```
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['Email'];
```

Comment: $headers .= 'De: '.$field_email."\r\n";

Comment: also... typo NOME should be NAME   <input type="Text" placeholder="Nome" name="Name">

Comment: typo in variable names $field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email']; should be $field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['Email'];

Comment: @JoeC these are helpful notes and comments on OPs coding, but they are not the cause for any failure of the emailer specifically

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your have created `mail` incorrectly, if you view the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php // http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

you will see that `mail($to, $usbject, $message, $headers);` and your version does not do this, you have no `$message` value in your mail item.

Also add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

To the top of your code to display error messages which will give you more feedback as to why your email sending is failing. And remove the `@` from your mail function until you are sure it works.

---

You should have

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ...
 $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
```

### Recommendation:

- Use UTF-8 character set, or UTF-16 if possible.
- Use a dedicated Mailer extension such as **PHPMailer**  or **Swift Mailer**
- Add error tracking (as exampled) across your code until you're sure it works.
- Eat five fresh fruit and vegetables a day.
- Also noted from PHP Mail:

> When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be
>   set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in
>   php.ini.
>
> Failing to do this will result in an error message similar to Warning:
>   mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header
>   missing. The From header sets also Return-Path under Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Add the form method here:

```
<form class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" action="contact.php">
```

Add the submit button name here:

```
 <button type="submit" name="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Enviar</button>
```

Change the php code to this :

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   // your code here..
    .
    .
    .
   // change the mail headers..
   $headers .= 'De: '.$field_email."\r\n";    
} ?>
```

Comment: I tried it but now I get the java alert saying that it failed to send :/